# Disable Saving taken or selected image from being saved to camera role

Tags: ios, swift, camera, camera-roll

I have looked for hours of any way to solve this, and if you can help at all, that would be amazing. I am using the imagePicker framework, ALCameraViewController, and I want to disable the annoying photo saving to camera role. I saw there was an issue opened on GitHub, but there was no answer on how to disable it. I tried to disable photoLibrary, but that just disables The Whole option of using the library. Is there any way at all, to use this framework and not have the images saved, because I cannot find out how. Or is there another framework where it is a full screen camera image picker with photo library? I have been searching for hours on a way to solve this, but I have had no luck. If there is anything you know, please leave a response. I just need to disable photos being saved to the users library. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you can change: "allowsLibraryAccess: false".
It works for me.

Here is my code :

`let cameraViewController = CameraViewController(croppingParameters: self.croppingParameters, allowsLibraryAccess: false) { [weak self] image, asset in
    self?.ivProfile.image = image
    self?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}`